# Having issue with translate function

Tags: d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I have coordinatesX and coordinatesY arrays. For example if I want to draw an arc between coordinatesX[1] and coordinatesY[4], a part of the code goes :

svg.append("path")

```
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", "red")
    .attr("transform", "translate(coordinatesX[1],coordinatesY[4])");
```

I am having problem with translate function. It says :

Error: Invalid value for  attribute transform="translate(coordinatesX[1],coordinatesY[4])"

How can I overcome this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not familiar with this, but it seems that the "coordinatesX[1],coordinatesY[4]" could be taken literally as the parameters of the function, maybe you need to form the proper string as:
"translate("+coordinatesX[1]+","+coordinatesY[4]+")".
Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, it works wonders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be a single string. As Salvador pointed out in the comments, in your example you were using `coordinatesX[1]` etc literally. But, if you concatenate, JavaScript creates a single string for you (if you add a number to a string, the result will be a string). In your case:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(" + coordinatesX[1] + "," + coordinatesY[4]) + ")");
```